# Implementing user authentication with Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Currently developing an extension of the basic network using node sdk. Im trying to figure out a way to implement user auth (REST api preferred). Is there any documentation that has this approach? 
(User object currently used by the node app is the default User1 created by registerUser.js in fabric-samples)